# Viability of PL/SQL Web Applications

Tags: web-services, plsql

Currently I'm researching a PL/SQL Web application that is in use in my organization. The web application runs completely in the database and returns HTML output thourgh the PL/SQK Web toolkit. I'm trying to find information on how actively developed this technology is, and how future proof it is for adding more dynamic features like AJAX in forms.

However, I can't find much on PL/SQL Web applications or what the major advantages/disadvantages are. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you heard of [Oracle Application Express (APEX)](http://apex.oracle.com)? That is Oracle's web application building tool, and it is built on the Web Toolkit.  These days not many people would use Web Toolkit directly to build apps, they would use APEX instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for an organisation that uses a mostly oracle stack, including oracle dbms and plsql. We have an advanced web application built using a javascript framework which makes AJAX calls to stored procedures returning JSON data.

**ADVANTAGES**

-Easy to write plsql code and to get new developers up to speed quickly

-You do not have to worry about database connections if you're writing stored procedures and packages

-pl/sql is being actively developed by oracle

**DISADVANTAGES**

-Cant move code to another DBMS easily

-Oracle can be very expensive

These are just some of my thoughts on it. Ease of use cannot be understated if you're building an application which deals with a lot of database data and transactions

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with lication. I am also working on a project at the moment, where a front end is being build with DOJO and the backend are REST APIs serving JSON implemented with PL/SQL. The application was originally built with PL/SQL Web Kit. However, we are creating a new RESTful architecture for new enhancements, and the plan is to eventually migrate the whole application to the new architecture.

The REST style architecture is being increasingly adopted. The trend is to build the front end completely with HTML and JavaScripts, not relying on any backend techonologies, PL/SQL or Java, to produce the web interface.  If this plays out as expected, then even J2EE will eventually fade away, not mentioning PL/SQL Web Kit. However, this does not deminish the use of PL/SQL in general.

When the backend is reduced to sole data services, PL/SQL may even have adavantage over Java and any other mid-tier lanaguges.  It is simply the best to handle Oracle data and it is the rigth place to host SQL. The key is to make it easy to produce JSON data, then it can play a bigger role in future application architecture.

This is just some random thoughts to share, as I have just comleted a PL/SQL REST Data Service framework for creating REST service APIs directly from Oracle database. In case that anybody is interested, here is a link to our site:

http://backlogic.net/